# Why is my enum assigned an incorrect integer in TypeScript class?

Tags: c#, enums, typescript

I have an enum declared like this:

```
public enum ProductSku
{
    NotSet = 0,
    CPO2D = 1,
    CPO3D = 2 
    CPO2Ds = 3,
    etc etc
}
```

> **Edit:** I can now see that TypeScript definition for `ProductSku` was incorrect, it looked like this:

```
export enum ProductSku {
    CPO2D = 0,
    CPO3D = 1,
    CPO2Ds = 2,
    CPO3Ds = 3,
    CPOComplete = 4,
    NotSet = 0,
}
```

As you can see I have assigned **1** to CPO2D but when I use it in a TypeScript class it is shown as having the value **0** (see screenshot below)

**Screenshot in Visual Studio:**

[image: Screenshot when hovering over in Visual Studio]

**What I have tried**

I have saved all, rebuilt the project as well as closing & reopening Visual Studio

I changed `CPO2D` to `CPO2Ds` (expecting the value to be **3**) which is being assigned **2**

There is probably a very simple explanation to this but I cannot see what I am doing wrong...

Comment: What is the value of ViewModels.Product.ProductSku.NotSet?

Comment: ViewModels.Product.ProductSku.NotSet is 0

Comment: My guess is intellisense using a prev (not current version) of some files (.ts or .js), when NotSet was not intrtoduced yet. Try to save all, build all close/reopen the code editor window etc. Make sure your build is successfull

Comment: I have saved all, rebuilt the project as well as closing & reopening Visual Studio

Comment: @NRKirby and issue still appear?

Comment: yes, the problem is still there...

Comment: Can you inspect the generated js file to see what is actually generated?

Comment: @SWeko I have updated my question (under 'What I have tried')

Comment: Can you post JS code that generates from `enum` definition?

Comment: @shytikov I've updated my original post

Comment: @NRKirby So you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks to @shytikov

Comment: Sometimes rebuilding all may not work if your references are not set up correctly (somewhere a reference is pointing to a cached DLL instead of the current DLL).  To assure this is not happening delete all copies of the DLL that the enum is compiled into.  There is a single DOS command that can do this.  From the highest common directory (ProjectRoot?) type: `del /s YourAssembly.dll`